# Proper verb for power outage

Tags: verbs

What verb is used for power outage?

> Power goes out everyday in the morning.

Is "goes out" correct verb for power outage or there is any other verb for it.
And what verb is used for power come back.

Comment: As a side note, whatever the power does, it doesn't do it [everyday](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/everyday). It does it [every day](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/every_day).

Answer (score 1):

[***Blackout***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_outage) comes to mind

[***Power restore***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_outage#Restoring_power_after_a_wide-area_outage) is what brings it back up

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, it's as simple as 'go off' (punctual) and 'be off' (durative).

> The power's gone off.
>
> When did the power go off?
>
> The power's still off.
>
> How long has the power been off?

Answer (score 0):

In the US we say,

"The power went out" or "The power was out"

"The power's going out" or "the power will be out"

"The power is out" is a common one you'll here!

Comment: May the power be with you this winter.